# How to send text to the Username field within https://mail.protonmail.com registration page?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, webdriverwait

I made proton mail script when I run that, it's working correctly but it's not typing username. This script did not type any text. Please help me!!

I had an error in second last line

here is my error:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
>   element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".input"}

I have a problem with selenium web driver

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    import time

    url = 'https://protonmail.com/'

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    driver.get(url)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn btn-default btn-short"]').click()

    time.sleep(10)

    driver.find_element_by_class_name('panel-heading').click()

    time.sleep(10)

    driver.find_element_by_id('freePlan').click()

    time.sleep(10)

    driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(Hamzalachistudios)

    time.sleep(10)
```

It's doing all good but it is not typing any text. Error name: `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: It'd be great if you can share the HTML snippet too. so that we can look at the Xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `WebDriverWait`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://protonmail.com/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="btn btn-default btn-short"]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'panel-heading'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'freePlan'))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("top"))

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'username'))).send_keys(Hamzalachistudios)
```

As @Amit Jain has answered you need to switch to the iframe so I added the wait to it...

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("top"))
```

Comment: hey, element is in iframe, so switch to be done, before click or any other method. He already added sleep so possibly this is not sync issue.

Comment: Please Help Me About Password This Script is now typing username but not typing a password Please Help Me!!

Answer (score 2):

Your element is in `iframe`, so first step before `click` or `sendKeys`, we need to `switch` to `iframe`

```
<input placeholder="Choose username" required="" 
name="username" messages="[object Object]" 
iframename="top" pattern=".{1,40}" id="username" class="input">

driver.switch_to.frame("top") //switching the frame by name
driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(Hamzalachistudios)
```

[image]

Comment: correct! you should switch to the iframe! I added the wait approach to my answer...  good catch!

Answer (score 1):

To send a *character sequence* to the **Username**  field as the the desired element are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    # chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://protonmail.com/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-default btn-short' and @href='signup']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row']//p[text()='Basic account with limited features']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right' and @id='freePlan']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='usernameWrap']//iframe[@title='Registration form']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='input' and @id='username']"))).send_keys("Hamza_Mirchi")
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: protonmail]

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Bro Please Help Me About Password He is Not Typing password Please Help Me!

Comment: @HamzaMirchi Can you raise a new question for your new requirement please? StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `iframe` which blocking to access the inputbox. You need to switch it to `iframe` first and then able to access the element.However you have added `time.sleep()` which actually slowdown your automation progress.You should use [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Try the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://protonmail.com/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.btn.btn-default.btn-short'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.panel-heading'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#freePlan'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".top")))
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'username'))).send_keys('Hamzalachistudios')
```

### Browser snapshot:

[image]